# How do I get ArgumentParser to behave the same when passing argv manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to refactor an argument parsing function I have to maintain, and to test the changes I call it using arguments passed from a test suite, but have discovered that the code does not behave the same as when using `sys.argv` by default
Here's a minimal reproduction that shows the issue.

1. Using default (sys.argv):

```py
import argparse
import sys

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", dest="foo", required=True,
                        help="Set Foo")
    parser.add_argument('inputfiles', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
    print("Parsing arguments: {}".format(sys.argv))
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("Args: {}".format(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_args()
```

Calling this  I get:

```sh
$ python ./test_argparse_def.py -f foo bar fizzbuzz
Parsing arguments: ['./test_argparse_def.py', '-f', 'foo', 'bar', 'fizzbuzz']
Args: Namespace(foo='foo', inputfiles=['bar', 'fizzbuzz'])
```

which is as expected.

2. Passing in sys.argv as a parameter (i.e according to my understanding, it should be using the same input) and using the parameter instead of a default.

```py
def parse_args(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=argv[0])
    parser.add_argument("-f", dest="foo", required=True,
                        help="Set Foo")
    parser.add_argument('inputfiles', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
    print("Parsing arguments: {}".format(argv))
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    print("Args: {}".format(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_args(sys.argv)
```

This gives:

```sh
$ python ./test_argparse.py -f foo bar fizzbuzz
Parsing arguments: ['./test_argparse.py', '-f', 'foo', 'bar', 'fizzbuzz']
usage: ./test_argparse.py [-h] -f FOO ...
./test_argparse.py: error: the following arguments are required: -f
```

which gives the unexpected error as -f is provided.

Am I using ArgumentParser incorrectly here and is there a way to get it to behave the same in the second case as in the first?
I've confirmed that the problem occurs in both python 3.5 and python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_args(sys.argv[1:])  <-- changed
```